# sqlite: Encrypting in-memory database before it touches secondary storage

Tags: c++, sqlite, encryption

I am musing about the possibility of switching from a C++ runtime relational database (std::maps for indexes, std::vectors for columns, etc) to using an in-memory sqlite database.  This would mainly be for code maintenance.  (Going back and looking at my code months later took my some time to re-acquaint myself with the schema I designed using C++ components; using SQL statements would at least be more self-documenting.)

Here's the hurdle, though: The data cannot touch secondary storage without being encrypted.  My current solution lends itself quite well to encryption before flushing.  Sqlite, however, appears to be its own opaque, self-contained ecosystem that isn't very conducive to manipulating the underlying database binary data as anything *but* a database.

So, I'm curious if anybody knows of a way, or has developed one, to put an encrypting hook in the sqlite backup system such that: memory -> encryption -> disc, and then in reverse.  Alternatively, I would also be fine just grabbing the in-memory database as a binary "blob" and do my own thing to it before I write it out myself (and reverse the process when loading it back in).  I don't see any such opportunities explicitly available in the sqlite backup API.

Note: I am not interested in using the SEE stuff, only the "public domain" sqlite offering.  I have sufficient cryptographic code in use already (via Qt) within my application, so I don't want competing systems.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: [sqlite3_serialize()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/serialize.html)

Comment: Ah, seems to be just the hooks I was looking for.  Thank you, CL.  :)